# Lotus Notes @formula language: Order of Actions wrong?

Tags: formula, lotus-domino, agent

I have defined an action with the following two commands:

```
@Prompt([...]; "1");
@Command([ToolsRunMacro];"(AGENT)");
@Prompt([...]; "2");
@If(@GetProfileField("PrivateProfile";"LENGTH";@UserName))>0;@PostedCommand([Compose];"FORM");"");
@Prompt([...]; "3");
```

But with the `@Prompt` commands I found out, that first of all each of the `@Prompt`messages (1-3) are displayed and **after that** the `AGENT` runs. But as the `AGENT` manipulates the `LENGTH`field, the `@IF` statement compares an 'obsolete' value.

Maybe each statement is executed at once? If yes: how can I prevent the agent from this behavior?

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [ToolsRunMacro] command will always run after all @Functions have executed first. There is no way to change this.

You can get a list of what commands will execute straight away vs after other functions that execute at the end, in the infocenter documentation.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_COMMAND.html

Also something to be aware on your code is that Profile documents are cached. So you might not in all cases see any changes made to the document straight away.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response.
Do you have any hint how to get agent run before the `@IF` statement?

Comment: Found it out myselft. Simply had to replace `ToolsRunMacro` with `RunAgent`.
Thank you for you help!